# Variable Selection with Kalman Filter

Tags: regression, factor-models, factor-loading, kalman

I'm trying to estimate factor loadings on portfolios over time for portfolios that are traded pretty frequently. I have a sense that several portfolios are loading on the Fama-French HML factor dynamically, and OLS estimates show that there is not a statistically significant loading on the HML factor.

I'd like to estimate the portfolios' loadings on the market and HML factors over time using the Kalman filter, but I also want to make sure I don't overfit a model and include extraneous variables. Is there a standard procedure for ensuring that I'm not adding unnecessary variables to a Kalman filter regression?